# How do you change the account running Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2008 builds post install

Tags: tfs

Just wondering the process to change the account running a TFS Build.  TFS was installed with the local network service account and needs to be changed to a domain account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the build service I'm pretty sure you just change the account used by the build service.  (In Manage Services right click on the Visual Studio Team Foundation Build service and then go to the Log On tab and edit the account)

You'll need to make sure that the new account has permissions to the drop location used by the builds.  Also the Build Agents's working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use TFSAdminUtil.exe? It's located in the TFS Installpath\Tools and you can run it using the "Changeaccount"-parameter. You then have to provide the old username and the new username and password afterwards.

```
TFSAdminUtil.exe ChangeAccount local\oldaccount domain\newaccount password
```

The use of this command is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253107.aspx). I used it to change the service account of the TFS and it worked, I don't know if it'll work for the build server, too.